# Non-B-completeness of finest locally convex topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, locally-convex-spaces

For an index set $A$ consider the locally convex direct sum $X_A := \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} \mathbb{R}_\alpha$ of $|A|$-many lines $\mathbb{R}_\alpha = \mathbb{R}$. Then $X_A$ is complete. It is known that if $A$ is countable then $X_A$ is $B$-complete (and even a Krein-Smulian space) and if $|A|^{\aleph_0} = |A|$ then $X_A$ is not $B$-complete (and not even $B_r$-complete).

The standard proof for the last fact is as follows. Let $X$ be an inf.-dim. vector space. If $A$ is a Hamelbasis of $X$ then $X = X_A$ as vector spaces. It is known that $X$ can be equipped with a complete norm if and only if $|A|^{\aleph_0} = |A|$ [Arthur H. Kruse, "Badly incomplete normed linear spaces", Mathematische Zeitschrift, 1964]. So in this case, take such a complete norm ($X$ is a Banach space) and denote the norm topology by $u$. Denote by $\tau^{lf}$ the finest locally convex topology on $X$ in which case $(X, \tau^{lf}) = X_A$ as locally convex spaces. Then the identity $id : (X, \tau^{lf}) \to (X, u)$ is continuous and almost open but not open since $\tau^{lf}$ is not normable and thus $\tau^{lf} \supsetneq u$. This implies that $X_A$ is not $B_r$-complete.

Question: Is it provable in $\textrm{ZFC}$ that $X_A$ is not $B$-complete for any uncountable set $A$?

Comment: Example 7.2.6 in the book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of Bonet and Perez Carreras states that $X_A$ is not B$_r$ complete whenever the cardinality of A is at least that of the continuum.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thank you. So the question reduces whether this is still true for all uncountable sets without assuming $\textrm{CH}$.